# Calculate average rate in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @table as table
(
    LedgerId int,
    Transaction_Type varchar(50),
    Inward_qty decimal (18,3),
    Inward_rate decimal (18,3)
)    

insert into @table 
values (1, 'Issue', 67.320, 473.66),
       (2, 'Receipt', 201.290, 657.90),
       (3, 'Receipt', 94.860, 473.66)

select * from @table
```

I want to calculate the average rate the formula is finding the receipt and subtract from issue remaining will be multiplied by the rate we will have the value than total value divided by total receipt qty and we will get an inward rate  I have no clue how to do this

Formula

- 201.290 - 67.320 = 133.970 (receipt - issue)
- 133.970 * 657.900 = 88,138.863(remaining receipt qty * rate) will get value
- 94.860 * 473.660 = 44,931.3876(receipt * rate) will get value
- 88,138.863 + 44,931.3876 = 1,33,070.2506 (sum of total value)
- 133.970 + 94.860 = 228.83(sum of total qty )
- 1,33,070.2506 / 228.83  (sum of total value) / (sum of total qty )
  = 581.5244967880086 thus 581.524 is average rate

output layout as per above calculation

```
declare @table1 as table
(
LedgerId int,
Transaction_Type varchar(50),
Inward_qty decimal (18,3),
Inward_rate decimal (18,3)

)
 insert into @table1 values(1,'Issue',67.320,473.66),(2,'Receipt',133.970,657.90),(3,'Receipt',94.860,473.66)
 
 select * , inward_Value = Inward_qty * Inward_rate into #temp from @table1

 declare @Qty decimal (18,3)
 declare @value decimal (18,3)

 set @Qty= (select sum(Inward_qty) from #temp where Transaction_Type ='Receipt' )
 set @value =(select sum(inward_Value) from #temp where Transaction_Type ='Receipt' )

 declare @Rate decimal (18,3) = @Value/@Qty
 select @Rate


 drop table #temp
```

Comment: what if there is no issue like for 3rd. or its like there will be receipt after every issue ?

Comment: I will check the condition if no issue then (receipt * rate) for all rows / (sum of total inward qty )

Comment: can you update final result layout as well ? like it will be 1 row , 2 row?

Comment: it might have multiple issues and receipt

Comment: final output will be one row and one column which is 581.524 ?

Comment: yes it can be set in new row or existing row does not matter

Comment: i have added the final result layout you can check it

Comment: What do you mean with "I have no clue how to do this" when the output of your last edit is  correct (=581.524) ???

Comment: it was just for demonstration purpose I have added already calculated static value to show how i need that after calculation

Comment: what is wrong with your query  isn't giving what you need ?

Comment: no why don't you understand in 2nd table I manually calculate  201.290 - 67.320 = 133.970 and put it into that table

Comment: see that now... I have posted query... Please mark if query was useful

Comment: thank you so much i have tested your query, just input data has been updated and you query is not providing proper ouput

Comment: input data order has been changed only

Comment: can anyone help with this?

Comment: I find the logic as you have described it to be really hard to follow, probably because the domain is just totally unclear.

Comment: can you just show me?